# C++ why returned const reference can be modified?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

This is something I can't get through right now: why `const string&` can be assigned to nonconst variable and further modified?

```
const string& shorter_s(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
  return s1.size() < s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}

int main() {
  const string s1 = "longer", s2 = "short";

  string result = shorter_s(s1, s2);
  cout << result << endl;
  result += "++";
  cout << result << endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
short
short++
```

Isn't `result` suppose to refer to `const string s2` object, which can't be modified by adding `"++"`?

Comment: `string const & result` would be a const reference, right now `result` is just a normal string variable copy-constructed with returned reference.

Comment: @VTT or `const string &result`. It would mean the same, right?

Comment: @GauravSehgal: Yes, just style difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string result = shorter_s(s1, s2);
```

Because `result` is not a reference. The result of the function call is assigned to a value variable, which means that it is copied. `result` doesn't refer to `s2` because it doesn't refer to any variable because it is not a reference.

If you want it *to refer* to something then make it a reference and you will see you can't make it a mutable reference:

```
string& result = shorter_s(s1, s2); // doesn't compile
const string& result = shorter_s(s1, s2); // OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you assign it to a non-constant non-reference variable. That means the value will be *copied* and you can modify the copy all you please.